# Db2 drop schema contents along with schema at once

Tags: schema

Is there a query in db2 9.7 control center wherein I can't `DELETE(DROP)` all the contents of my schema (including the schema) at once?

My other option is to drop/delete the objects first and then DROP schema..
But I want to `DROP THE ENTIRE SCHEMA WITH ALL OBJECTS` at once.

`DROP SCHEMA <schema_name> CASCADE/RESTRICT` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA` procedure is what you're looking for.

> The `ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA` procedure is used to drop a specific schema and all objects contained in it.
>   <sup>http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0022036.htm</sup>

Comment: Since the link appears to be broken here is a new one: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=procedure-admin-drop-schema-drop-schema. But keep in mind that this procedure has output arguments so you need to pass variables to it. Put it in a stored procedure and call that.

Answer (score 1):

First drop all the tables in the schema.
Then try to delete the schema using

```
DROP SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME RESTRICT
```

webchain.in have sample java program, explains how to delete the schema using java program

in case drop schema fails after dropping all the tables with the error SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, try command

grant dbadm on database to USER_NAME